# How to send url in SMS?

Tags: iphone, url, ios4, url-rewriting, sms

I am sending the SMS from iPhone application using the below code, I have to send the url also ,so I want to know what should be url format so that the when receiver(iphone user) of the SMS tap on url, the url should be opened in the browser by itself.
The SMS body is coming from server,so I am extracting the SMS body content from server response and passing to SMS sending code.

```
NSString *smsBody = @"I am sending the google url: www.google.com";//as a sample sms body  

if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

    MFMessageComposeViewController *smsComposerController = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [smsComposerController setBody:smsBody];
    // smsComposerController.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"+19999999999",nil];
    smsComposerController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:smsComposerController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that making sure that your URLs are prefixed with http:// would probably give the iPhone the best opportunity to identify that the SMS body content is a URL Link. It's similar to the way that iTunes links work in Mobile Safari and the iPhone knows to switch applications to the App Store app to view in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send url in sms in both the formats
1. `http://www.google.com`
2. `www.google.com`

iPhone will detect both the format as a url and on tap of the url link it will open in browser itself.